# Import (parse) large CSV file with php

Tags: php, csv, fgetcsv

I have large CSV file of the data which i need to import using php. CSV contains 50 000 plus rows and 12 columns. Size up to 10MB.

example of the csv:

```
1;B*2332IF2.8;Hikvision DS-2CD2332-I F2.8 DOME;177.0000;146.2817;177.0000;141.2800;134.2200;0.0000;670.0000;B-BAL,;114.0000
1;B*2432FIF2.8;Hikvision DS-2CD2432F-I F2.8 CUBE;152.0000;126.0000;152.0000;119.7000;114.0000;0.0000;400.0000;B-BAL,;118.0000
1;B*2T32I8F12;Hikvision DS-2CD2T32-I8 F12 BULLET;214.0000;176.0000;214.0000;158.0000;142.0000;0.0000;0.0000;B-BAL,;154.0000
0;B*2T42WDI8F4;Hikvision DS-2CD2T42WD-I8 F4;159.0000;131.4056;0.0000;125.0000;125.0000;0.0000;1300.0000;B-BAL,;134.0000
1;B*7604NIE1;Hikvision DS-7604NI-E1;128.0000;105.7856;0.0000;0.0000;0.0000;2.0000;1000.0000;B-BAL,;124.0000
```

I try to use fgetcsv() function, but no success. I have increased time and memory but  no success...

```
if (($h = fopen("my_large.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) 
{
  // Convert each line into the local $data variable
  while (($data = fgetcsv($h, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) 
  {     
    // Read the data from a each single line and processing... writing to the database
  }

  // Close the file
  fclose($h);
}
```

Please help to solve the problem.

Comment: what you mean with "no success"?

Comment: @ u_mulder No PC do not explodes :) I have set time limit up to 1800 sec. And this time do not enough for that. Getting: Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 1800 seconds exceeded in....

Comment: I have tried even smaller file, where 5000 rows, also time was exceeded.

Comment: Do you execute this code by request? It should be done with a command line, not by request.

Comment: I need to run this code in cron job. How to do with a command line?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php

Comment: 10 MB is not really so big. I suspect the bottleneck here might be the database where you're storing data. You can comment out database code and measure execution time. In any case, can't you just increase the allowed time?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález yes you are right. this is DB issue. I just checked it, without data saving. 30000 rows with 12 columns have read per 1 sec. With saving data to the database its took very long time... about 45 minutes. I think it is incredible long time. It is here some way decrease that time?